# using minus in sql server on sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am learning sql server and new here please forgive me if I ask stupid question. My question is

*Find the difference in total Sales amount between the month of Nov and Dec for the year 2007*

This is my query -->

```
select novsales,decsales 
FROM (
    SELECT saleskey,sum(salesamount) as novsales 
    FROM FactSales 
    WHERE month(DateKey) = 11 
    AND YEAR(DateKey) =2007 
) as a 
INNER join (
    SELECT saleskey,sum(SalesAmount) as decsales 
    FROM FactSales 
    WHERE month(DateKey) = 12 
    AND YEAR(DateKey) =2007
) as b on a.SalesKey = b.SalesKey
```

Comment: There is better way to do your query but if your query is working and you are just asking how to subtract the two just put novsales - decsales

Comment: no it isnt working plz tell me how to do it i wanna understand that

Comment: What does "not working" mean? If you're getting a error, then post it. If it's not working as intended, then post sample and expected results, along with the results you are getting.

Comment: See my answer.  You are missing a group by.

Answer (score 1):

While your query is correct but you should use FULL JOIN as there is a possibility that for a sales key there might not be a row on left or right

```
select a.saleskey,
novsales=ISNULL(novsales,0),
decsales =ISNULL(decsales ,0),
salesdiff=ISNULL(novsales,0)-ISNULL(decsales ,0)
FROM (
    SELECT saleskey,sum(salesamount) as novsales 
    FROM FactSales 
    WHERE month(DateKey) = 11 
    AND YEAR(DateKey) =2007 
    GROUP BY saleskey
) as a 
full outer join (
    SELECT saleskey,sum(SalesAmount) as decsales 
    FROM FactSales 
    WHERE month(DateKey) = 12 
    AND YEAR(DateKey) =2007
    GROUP BY saleskey
) as b on a.SalesKey = b.SalesKey
```

But ....
another shorter way would be to do it in one go like below

```
SELECT 
    saleskey,
    novsales = sum(CASE when month(DateKey) =11 then salesamount else 0 end) as novsales,
    decsales = sum(CASE when month(DateKey) =12 then salesamount else 0 end) as decsales,
    salesdiff=sum(CASE when month(DateKey) =11 then salesamount else 0 end) - sum(CASE when month(DateKey) =12 then salesamount else 0 end)
FROM FactSales 
WHERE month(DateKey) in ( 11 ,12)
AND YEAR(DateKey) =2007 
group by saleskey
```

Comment: This is still vastly over complicating things

Answer (score 1):

Your query is unnecessarily joining the table to itself and using functions in your `where` which will have a negative impact on your query performance, as you can not utilise any indexes on the table.  Just use some conditional aggregates within a `case` expression:

```
select SalesKey
      ,sum(case when month(DateKey) = 11 then salesamount end)
       - sum(case when month(DateKey) = 12 then salesamount end) as SalesDiff
from FactSales 
where DateKey >= '20071101'
  and DateKey < '20080101'
group by SalesKey;
```

Note that I am comparing the `DateKey` value with `date` values and that the query is looking for `greater or equal to the start of November` and `less than the start of January`.  This is required is you are using `datetime` values to ensure all potential `December` records.

---

Looking at your question again, it looks like you may be misrepresenting your data and don't want to be grouping on your `SalesKey` column at all, which would make sense from the name.  If that is the case, your query is even simpler:

```
select sum(case when month(DateKey) = 11 then salesamount end)
       - sum(case when month(DateKey) = 12 then salesamount end) as SalesDiff
from FactSales 
where DateKey >= '20071101'
  and DateKey < '20080101'
```

Comment: missing a group by

Comment: @paparazzo  Right you are!

Comment: That is going to return multiple rows.  Odd presentation.

Comment: @paparazzo  What do you mean?  This will return one row per `SalesKey`, which is how the the OP has suggested their data is to be aggregated.  If they don't need to group by the `SalesKey` they can just remove it and have one value returned from the `case` expressions

Comment: On second thought it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

if those are numbers (and they should be)

select novsales,  decsales, novsales - decsales as difference

Demo

```
declare @t table (int1 int, int2 int);
insert @t values (1,2), (5,3);
select *, int1 - int2 as diff
from @t
```

I think the syntax will fail.  You need a `group by`.

```
SELECT saleskey, sum(salesamount) as novsales 
FROM FactSales 
WHERE month(DateKey) = 11 
AND YEAR(DateKey) = 2007 
group by saleskey
```